# ls there a native way to create a time string?

Tags: javascript, time

I modified the code below to create a time string which looks exactly the way I want it.  It is how my Timex watch displays time.

Is there a native way to do this?  I feel like I must have re-invented the wheel as surely many have needed this method before me.

```
const api = {};

// gets a time string which is human readable using the Date object
api.getTime = function() {
  const date = new Date();

  // get minutes and add a 0 if needed
  let min = date.getMinutes();
  min =  (parseInt(min, 10) < 10 ? '0' : '') + min;

  // get hours, determine AM or PM and change to 12 hours
  // not preceding 0 is needed
  let hour = date.getHours();
  const amPm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hour = ( hour % 12 ) || 12;

  // get seconds and add a 0 if needed
  let sec = date.getSeconds();
  sec =  (parseInt(sec, 10) < 10 ? '0' : '') + sec;

  return `${hour}:${min}:${sec} ${amPm}`;
}

module.exports = api;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is definitely helping if you take a look at [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), from the documentation:

> Return the time portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions.

You can test out this function as the following:

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(date);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: looks much better as you can even modify the language using the options.